# BrowserRouter shows Error when Page is refreshed | React-router-v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Using **HashRouter**, the route works well in all circumstances but when **BrowserRouter** is used , it shows error when the *page is refreshed*.

Here's the code for the Route which I wrapped under HashRouter and BrowserRouter:

```js
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/trip-detail" component={TripDetail} />
          <Route exact path="/booking" component={TripBooking} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
```

Here's the screenshot I get while refreshing:

[image: router error]

Comment: On local ? How do you host your app ?

Comment: Yeah I am testing in local dev environment, I use firebase for hosting

Comment: can you post your index.js file where you are importing BrowserRouter, are you passing any history to BrowserRouter?

Comment: You can use [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) with historyApiFallback

Comment: @Aaqib no I am not passing history to BrowserRouter, but While debugging I found that the components are receiving history and other related props(location,etc)

Comment: @GabrielBleu Let me try that if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Thanks @GabrielBleu, Your solution worked like a charm. It was not react router which was creating this error. It was my webpack(server) config which was unknown to get a route to my components.

The only thing I had updated in my webpack config was to add this code

```js
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: '/',
    },
  },
```